# Is there a name for those concrete categories in which every subset / quotient set inherits the structure of an object in at most one way?

Tags: category-theory, terminology

The following situation seems to occur a lot in abstract algebra:

We have a category $\mathbf{C}$, concrete over $\mathbf{Set}$, that satisfies:

1. For every object $Y$ of $\mathbf{C}$ and every set $S$ and every injective function $f:S \rightarrow UY$, there is at most one $X \in U^{-1}(S)$ such that there exists a morphsim $\varphi : X \rightarrow Y$, satisfying $U(\varphi) = f$.
2. For every object $X$ of $\mathbf{C}$ and every set $S$ and every surjective function $f:UX \rightarrow S$, there is at most one $Y \in U^{-1}(S)$ such that there exists a morphsim $\varphi : X \rightarrow Y$, satisfying $U(\varphi) = f$.

These conditions hold, for example, if $\mathbf{C}$ is any of $\mathbf{Grp},\mathbf{Ring}$, $\mathbf{Lat}$, and even $\mathbf{Field}$. They fail if $\mathbf{C}$ is any of $\mathbf{Grph},\mathbf{Pos}$, or $\mathbf{Top}$.

> **Questions.**
>
> **Q0.** Do either or both of the above conditions have a name?
>
> **Q1.** Are they related to any other familiar categorical properties?

Comment: My guess would be that this has to do with the fact that $U$ reflects isomorphisms.